# javafx css only applied to currently shown elements

Tags: css, javafx

I´m trying to implement a very basic, simple and quiet typical dialog showing a list of checkboxes and a button for selecting all these checkboxes of the list.

The actual selection is working as expected. I also change the background color of the actual box showing the check symbol. But this color is only applied to the checkboxes visible without scrolling the list. When scrolling down the list you can see that all checkboxes are selected but the color is not set.

I´m using JDK10.

How can I force applying the color?

EDIT:
When first scrolling down and then clicking "select all" all colors of the previous checkboxes are also set correctly. But still not the following ones.

EDIT:
The same effect occurs when filtering the boxes using `instanceof` and change the colors by Region#setBackground(...).

```
package javafxcssbroken;

import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXCssBroken extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<CheckBox> listView = new ListView();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            listView.getItems().add(new CheckBox("Element " + i));
        }

        Button markAll = new Button("Select all");
        markAll.setOnAction(aevt -> {
            Color newColor = Color.BLUE;
            listView.getItems().stream()
                    .forEach(checkbox -> {
                        checkbox.setSelected(true);
                        checkbox.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream()
                                .forEach(child -> child.setStyle(new StringJoiner(", ", "-fx-background-color: rgba(", ")")
                                .add(Double.toString(255 * newColor.getRed()))
                                .add(Double.toString(255 * newColor.getGreen()))
                                .add(Double.toString(255 * newColor.getBlue()))
                                .add(Double.toString(newColor.getOpacity()))
                                .toString()));
                    });
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(listView, markAll);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFXCssBroken");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
So a solution should be to introduce a class representing the data itself and also its associations discussed in the comments.

JavaFXCssBroken.java

```
package javafxcssbroken;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;

/**
 * @param <I> The type of the items to display.
 * @param <G> The type of the groups to associate items with.
 */
public class JavaFXCssBroken<I, G> extends Application {

    private ListView<AssociatedItem<I, G>> listView;
    private Set<I> items;
    private Map<G, Color> groups;
    private Optional<G> currentGroup;

    public JavaFXCssBroken(Set<I> items, Map<G, Color> groups, Optional<G> initialGroup){
        this.items = items;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.currentGroup = initialGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        listView = new ListView();
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> {
            ListCell<AssociatedItem<I, G>> cell = new ListCell<>();
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                if(!cell.isEmpty() && newVal != null && newVal.getGroup().isPresent()){
                    cell.setBackground(new Background(
                            new BackgroundFill(groups.get(newVal.getGroup().get()), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                }
            });
            cell.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
                if(newVal){
                    cell.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                }
            });
            return cell;
        });

        items.stream().forEach(item -> listView.getItems().add(new AssociatedItem(item)));

        Button markAll = new Button("Select all");
        markAll.setOnAction(aevt -> {
            listView.getItems().stream()
                    .forEach(item -> item.setGroup(currentGroup));
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(listView, markAll);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFXCssBroken");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

AssociatedItem.java

```
package javafxcssbroken;

import java.util.Optional;

public class AssociatedItem<I, G> {

    private I item;
    private Optional<G> group;

    public AssociatedItem(I item) {
        this.item = item;
        group = Optional.empty();
    }

    public I getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(I item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Optional<G> getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Optional<G> group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return item.toString();
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package javafxcssbroken;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Map<Integer, Color> groups = Map.of(0, Color.RED, 1, Color.BLUE);
        Set<String> items = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            items.add("Elements " + i);
        }
        new JavaFXCssBroken(items, groups, Optional.of(0)).start(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

At this point colors are set to all elements but the update of the colors is only applied when starting to scroll. Is it enough to introduce AssociatedItems as Observable?

Comment: why do you add controls as data? don't ..

Comment: what happens, is that your code styles children that are not yet created - that is it does nothing for items that had not yet been added to the scenegraph. So back to my first comment ;) What do you want to achieve?

Comment: It is true. Usually i would not use controls as data.
What I want to archieve: These entries can be associated with groups (represented by colors). So when I select a checkbox it gets associated with a certain group. To show the user which items are associated with groups the check symbol is used. To show the user to which group an element is associated the color is used. That´s the idea.

Comment: These groups are not known from beginning. These are generated dynamically. More precisely I have a wizard, which lets you first create groups (and so colors) and on the next page associate elements with these groups. The association with groups itself is working perfectly but the optical coloring...

Comment: as always, the way out is to _not_ try to solve this in the view (which _must not_ contain any data related logic), but in a model - use some backing data that manages the "grouping" and exposes it as  a property of the item. Then implement a custom cell that updates itself (in update item) according to that property

Comment: looking at your edit, it seems that I wasn't clear enough: your styling fails for all checkboxes that _had not yet been shown_ - technically, because a) they are created by the skin (of the checkbox) b) the skin is created on adding the control to the scenegraph c) cells are re-used and added only when scrolled into the visible region. Applied to your context: you style the children of all checkboxes, even if they have not yet been visible at any time and consequently has no children - so your styling is a no-op. No wonder you see the effect you are seeing ;)

Comment: Neither the data nor the groups nor the associations are stored within the view. The only purpose of these colors is giving the user optical feedback about which items are currently associated to which color. It is in no way influencing the data.
But you are right I may try to use a custom ListCell.

Comment: don't see anything "dynamic" in your edited example (the one introducing a wrapper round your item) ... and that was the core problem, as I understood you?

Comment: and listening to the item property is not the fx way of updating ... implement updateItem is: all you have to do is to make group a property (forget about Optional ..) and use and configure the list with an extractor so its firing an update event on change

Comment: The implementation based on these two listener is based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246496/javafx-custom-list-cell-updateitem-being-called-a-lot

Comment: I did not post the part where it acutally gets dynamic since this would be a quite big bunch of code.
If you want to see more of the code initially posted take a look at https://github.com/TrackerSB/Green2/blob/master/ParentExecutables/MemberManagement/src/main/java/bayern/steinbrecher/green2/selection/SelectionGroupController.java. Since the suggested approach is not working as expected it is not yet part of the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As kleopatra suggested overriding updateItem(...) and using an extractor works.

Main.java remains the same as in the last edit of the question.

AssociatedItem.java

```
package javafxcssbroken;

import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;

public class AssociatedItem<I, G> {

    private final ObjectProperty<I> item = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final ObjectProperty<Optional<G>> group = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public AssociatedItem(I item) {
        this.item.set(item);
        group.set(Optional.empty());
    }

    public ObjectProperty<I> itemProperty() {
        return item;
    }

    public I getItem() {
        return itemProperty().get();
    }

    public void setItem(I item) {
        this.item.set(item);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Optional<G>> groupProperty() {
        return group;
    }

    public Optional<G> getGroup() {
        return groupProperty().get();
    }

    public void setGroup(Optional<G> group) {
        this.group.set(group);
    }
}
```

JavaFXCssBroken.java

```
package javafxcssbroken;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableObjectValue;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @param <I> The type of the items to display.
 * @param <G> The type of the groups to associate items with.
 */
public class JavaFXCssBroken<I, G> extends Application {

    private ListView<AssociatedItem<I, G>> listView;
    private Set<I> items;
    private ObservableValue<ObservableList<AssociatedItem<I, G>>> associatedItems
            = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(
                    FXCollections.observableArrayList(i -> new Observable[]{i.itemProperty(), i.groupProperty()}));
    private Map<G, Color> groups;
    private Optional<G> currentGroup;

    public JavaFXCssBroken(Set<I> items, Map<G, Color> groups, Optional<G> initialGroup) {
        this.items = items;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.currentGroup = initialGroup;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        listView = new ListView();
        listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<AssociatedItem<I, G>>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(AssociatedItem<I, G> item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item == null || empty) {
                    setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
                } else {
                    item.getGroup().ifPresent(group -> {
                        setBackground(new Background(
                                new BackgroundFill(groups.get(group), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                    });
                    setText(item.getItem().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        listView.itemsProperty().bind(associatedItems);

        items.stream().forEach(item -> {
            associatedItems.getValue().add(new AssociatedItem<>(item));
        });

        Button markAll = new Button("Select all");
        markAll.setOnAction(aevt -> {
            listView.getItems().stream()
                    .forEach(item -> item.setGroup(currentGroup));
        });

        VBox vbox = new VBox(listView, markAll);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFXCssBroken");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: glad you found a solution :) Though .. the Optional as property is rather weird and isn't safe: its content can be changed without sending a notification. In your shoes I would drop it and expose the value directly (it's a property and as such a kind-of container around a possible null)

Comment: I'm not sure about that since the content of an Optional cannot be changed using a setter. When setting a new value I have to create a new Optional so a notification should be sent.

Comment: ohh ... then I have been showing that I never use that sugared null <g>

Answer (score 1):

Kleopatra is right. But assuming it is a simple example or training (even if you should take the good practice as soon as possible i.e even during the training), just use the css strength, create a stylesheet with this content :

StyleCheckbox.css

```
.check-box:selected >  .box {
   -fx-background-color:blue;
}
```

And modify your exisiting code by commenting the useless mechanic, and by adding the stylesheet you just create. :

```
markAll.setOnAction(aevt -> {
     // Color newColor = Color.BLUE;
     listView.getItems().stream().forEach(checkbox -> {
        checkbox.setSelected(true);
        // checkbox.getChildrenUnmodifiable().stream()
        // .forEach(child -> child.setStyle(new StringJoiner(", ", "-fx-background-color:
        // rgba(", ")")
        // .add(Double.toString(255 * newColor.getRed()))
        // .add(Double.toString(255 * newColor.getGreen()))
        // .add(Double.toString(255 *
        // newColor.getBlue())).add(Double.toString(newColor.getOpacity()))
        // .toString()));
     });
  });

VBox vbox = new VBox(listView, markAll);
vbox.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("StyleCheckbox.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: agreed, nevertheless the OP might have hit a bug: setting a style on a control (via setstyle) has no effect if the control is not part of the scenegraph at the time of setting. Happens with a plain checkbox as graphic of a Label as well. Would expect to work ...

Comment: .. and does - children of checkbox are created by its skin, styling children that are not yet created is  ... ;)

Comment: I should confess I do not understand why it does not work after having read your first remark, and I was investigating. Component's skins is something fuzzy to me, I have to go into it in depth when I'll find a while.

Comment: Since the colors are chosen dynamically I would have to create css classes also dynamically to be able to associate these with the checkboxes.